# rails 3.2 model convert to rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I try to change my rails-3.2-model to rails 4, but I dont understand it.
Maybe you can help me to change it.
**3.2:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation
  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :username, :on => :create
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :username

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
end
```

**4.0.4:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: true}, length: {minimum: 3, too_short: "must have at least %{count} characters"}
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: true}
  validates :password_hash

end
```

I tried to get rid off the `attr_accessible` and `attr_accessor`, but I don't know how.
`attr_accessor :password` and `attr_accessible [...] :password_confirmation` are not stored in the database, so how can I use it in my view?

**EDIT:**
*View:*

```
<p>Sign Up</p>
    <%= form_for @user, :as => :user, :url => auth_sign_up_path, :html => {:class => 'navbar-form', :role => 'login'} do |user_form_builder| %>
        <p>
          <%= user_form_builder.label 'name:' %><br/>
          <%= user_form_builder.text_field :name %>
          <%= show_field_error(@user, :name) %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= user_form_builder.label 'email:' %><br/>
          <%= user_form_builder.text_field :email %>
          <%= show_field_error(@user, :email) %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= user_form_builder.label 'password:' %><br/>
          <%= user_form_builder.password_field :password %>
          <%= show_field_error(@user, :password) %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= user_form_builder.label 'password confirmation:' %><br/>
          <%= user_form_builder.password_field :password_confirmation %>
          <%= show_field_error(@user, :password_confirmation) %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= user_form_builder.submit 'Sign Up' %>
          <%= user_form_builder.submit 'Clear Form', :type => 'reset' %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
```

*Controller:*

```
def sign_up
    @user = User.new
  end

  def register
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.valid?
      @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      flash[:notice] = 'Welcome.'
      redirect_to :root
    else
      render :action => "sign_up"
    end
  end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

*Model:*

```
require 'bcrypt'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  before_save :encrypt_password
  after_save :clear_password

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: true}, length: {minimum: 3, too_short: "must have at least %{count} characters"}
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: true}
  validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 8, too_short: "must have at least %{count} characters"}, :confirmation => true #password_confirmation attr

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    super # must allow the active record to initialize!
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def self.authenticate_by_email(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def self.authenticate_by_name(name, password)
    user = find_by_username(name)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end

  def clear_password
    self.password = nil
  end

end
```

*Migration:*

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_hash
      t.string :password_salt
      t.string :cal_owner, :array => true, :default => '{}'
      t.string :cal_joined, :array => true, :default => '{}'

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

*Routes:*

```
Calendar::Application.routes.draw do

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'welcome#index'

  get "auth/sign_up" => "auth#sign_up"
  get "auth/sign_in" => "auth#sign_in"
  get "auth/sign_out" => "auth#sign_out"
  get "auth/settings"
  get "auth/pwd_reset"
  get "welcome/index"

  post "auth/sign_in" => "auth#login"
  post "auth/sign_up" => "auth#register"
end
```

[image: Database]

I used a tutorial, but I didnt know why the author add this:

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
        super # must allow the active record to initialize!
        attributes.each do |name, value|
          send("#{name}=", value)
        end
      end
```

The author wrote:

> For each key-value pair (hash) we assign the value to the attribute by
>   calling the "send" function (all method calls in Ruby are actually
>   messages.)
>
> Important:
>
> We don't actually need to do this for the User class because the
>   constructor provided by Rails will allow us to do a "mass assign" from
>   a hash as long as the fields that we are assigning have been
>   designated as "attr_accessible", which they have.  However, there are
>   cases when one wants to initialize several fields (such as ID's in a
>   many-to-many table) that are not intended to be accessible to a view
>   but instead are designated with an "attr_accessor" instead.  The above
>   function is a simple way of providing safe mass assign capability for
>   internal constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I now understand, your user table has effectively 4 columns in addition to the ID, created at etc.:

- name
- email
- password_hash
- password_salt

On your view you have fields:

- name
- email
- password
- password_confirmation

Your controller looks correct.  The `user_params` method is whitelisting the 4 fields from the view and letting them be passed through to the User model for creating a new user.

In your model you need to make 2 changes.

Firstly you should remove `name` and `email` from the `attr_accessor` line:

```
attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation
```

You only need `password` and `password_confirmation`.  The reason for this is since name and email are columns on the database, Rails will automatically give you the getter and setter methods for these attributes.  `attr_accessor` then saves you having to explicitly write getter and setter methods for `password` and `password_confirmation` and lets them be populated automatically on creating a new user with the values that come through from the view.

Secondly you should remove the `initialize` method.  `User` inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` and will be able to build new user records quite happily without the need for a constructor.

The author of the tutorial included the constructor for doing mass-assignment.  However in Rails 4 this has been changed to use strong parameters so that it is now the responsibility of the controller to state which parameters can be passed to the model.  You do this correctly in your `user_params` method in the controller.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think your explanation is good enough. Thank you. I'll this and will mark it as solved, if I get it works.

Comment: I have to fix some more problems. ATM I can't mark it as solved.

Comment: It didn't work, because there are only "" in my database and not the username and so on. Any Idea ? I think I should asked a new Question.?!

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.  Could you edit your question with exactly what is in your user table please.  I'm a bit confused with what you are trying to change in your model - to go from Rails 3.2 to 4.0, it is only strictly necessary to replace `attr_accessible` with strong parameters from the controller.  All of the `attr_accessor` logic you had before can remain.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just edited the Question. I should add that I am new to Rails & Ruby.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question - I've updated my answer.  Hope it can help you.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help. I'll try it and tell you, whether it works. Seems legit that email and name shouldnt attr_acessible. That small mistake makes me such frustrated :|